# Grails simple-blog BlogEntry class how to use FindByTagAndLockedAndPublish in one short

Tags: grails, grails-2.0, grails-plugin, grails-domain-class, grails-controller

I am using simple-blog plugin in grails. i have code

```
class OodlesBlogEntry extends org.grails.blog.BlogEntry implements Taggable, Commentable{

Boolean isProtected = false;

}


  def entries =  OodlesBlogEntry.findAllByTag(params.tag.trim(), [max:5, offset:params.offset, sort:"dateCreated", order:"desc"])
```

And

```
entries.findAll { it.published }
```

these are working fine but the problem is i want to use both statement together so that it can give me perfect output. something like.

```
def entries = OodlesBlogEntry.findAllByTagAndPublishAndLocked(params.tag.trim(), true, false [max:5, offset:params.offset, sort:"dateCreated", order:"desc"])
```

But this statement is not working. please help me to solve this issue.

Error when i put both in one line.

```
| Error 2014-10-06 12:40:52,133 [http-bio-8080-exec-5] ERROR errors.GrailsExceptionResolver  - InvalidPropertyException occurred when processing request: [GET] /blog/tagged/android
No property found for name [tag] for class [class com.oodles.blog.OodlesBlogEntry]. Stacktrace follows:
Message: No property found for name [tag] for class [class com.oodles.blog.OodlesBlogEntry]
    Line | Method
->>  104 | methodMissing in org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormStaticApi
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    569 | byTag         in com.oodles.blog.BlogController$$EOrtPHk8
|    198 | doFilter . .  in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter
|     63 | doFilter      in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter
|     53 | doFilter . .  in grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.filter.GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationFilter
|     49 | doFilter      in grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.authentication.RequestHolderAuthenticationFilter
|     82 | doFilter . .  in grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.authentication.logout.MutableLogoutFilter
|    270 | doFilter      in com.planetj.servlet.filter.compression.CompressingFilter
|   1145 | runWorker . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run           in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    745 | run . . . . . in java.lang.Thread
```

Comment: Can you post the error that you get?

Comment: @Iván that would be cheating. We just need more practice at mindreading.

Comment: I edited Question, hope this will help more to understand my problem, its real problem. @BurtBeckwith its not cheating i am facing this issue.

Comment: It was a joke. I always find it weird when developers who must have been given information-free bug reports in the past ("this doesn't work. please fix it") do exactly the same thing to other developers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for the error is that `findAllByTag` is not a GORM dynamic finder. It's a method that is added by the taggable plugin to any domain classes that implement the `Taggable` interface.

Because `findAllByTag` is not a dynamic finder, you cannot combine it with other dynamic finders, e.g. `findAllByTagAndPublish`.

When you install the taggable plugin, 2 additional classes are added to your domain, `Tag` and `TagLink`. The latter joins a tag with a domain object that has been tagged with it, e.g.

```
mysql> select * from tag_links limit 5;
+----+---------+--------+---------+-----------+
| id | version | tag_id | tag_ref | type      |
+----+---------+--------+---------+-----------+
|  1 |       0 |      1 |       1 | blogEntry |
|  2 |       0 |      2 |       1 | blogEntry |
|  3 |       0 |      3 |       1 | blogEntry |
|  4 |       0 |      4 |       2 | blogEntry |
|  5 |       0 |      5 |       2 | blogEntry |
+----+---------+--------+---------+-----------+
```

You could certainly write an SQL query that would retrieve all the published, unlocked blog entries with a particular tag, but it wouldn't be pretty. You might even be able to use HQL, but personally I wouldn't bother. I understand that your current approach requires you to run 2 queries where only 1 should be necessary, but does this really matter? Unless you have hundreds/thousands of blog posts (which seems unlikely) it's not going to make much practical difference.

### Update

Alternatively, you could get all blog entries with a particular tag via:

```
def entries =  OodlesBlogEntry.findAllByTag(params.tag)
```

Then you can do filtering out unpublished or locked tags, sorting, and pagination in Groovy code:

```
def filteredEntries = entries.findAll{ it.published && !it.locked }
def sortedEntries = filteredEntries.sort { it.title }

def max = 5 
def offset = params.offset

// TODO check the size of sortedEntries and adjust the pagination params to prevent an 
// IndexOutOfBoundsException
def entriesPage = filteredEntries.sort[offset..<offset + max]
```

Comment: u r right ... but issue is that i want to show 5 blogs each time but when i search and filter them by published and locked its may send me 2, 3 or sometime zero blogs, even their are so may blogs.. any suggestion ..?

Comment: is it good approach to do so ? and how do i manage offset ? sorting ?

Comment: I've updated again to explain how to do pagination and sorting

Comment: Thank you so much and i am waiting for the solution so that i can take my all data in one shot...and meanwhile i m using this idea... thanks a lot ... :)

Comment: @SaNtOsHSinGh the only way you're going to be able to get all the data "in one shot" is by writing a query in SQL/HQL. It won't be possible using dynamic finders.